# How to ensure that catch return value differs from try return value when returning integers or doubles

Tags: java, return, double, try-catch

Hi everyone this is my first question so I apologies if this has been answered somewhere before but I couldn't find an answer to the question so I'm posting it here.

In the case where your method has a return value that can be positive or negative, and you are unsure of the range the return value, what value should you return if you get an exception?

For example in the method below-

```
public double calculateDifference(String studentName, String quizName) {
  try {
      Quiz quiz = quizDAO.retrieve(quizName);
      double averageScore = quiz.getAverageScore();
      Student student = quiz.getStudent(studentName);
      double score = student.getScore();
      return score - averageScore;
   } catch (NullPointerException e) {
      return -1;
  }
}
```

Assuming score and average score have a large range, what if my return value in my catch is equal to the value returned when there is no exception?

For example, score=2, and average score=3, so I will get -1 as a return value.

When I get that return value I'm unsure of whether an exception was caught or not.

What I'm asking I guess is if there is a way, when caught, to return a unique double value that doesn't clash with other possible return values.

Comment: It might be simpler to check for null values before calling the method.

Comment: @patrick-hainge Thanks for the prompt reply and that is true. However, I'm doing an assignment where I have to follow a sequence diagram and thus only can call the getStudent method in the calculateDifference method

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simple: `NullPointerExceptions` are **bugs**.

You do not catch them.

You debug them to understand their cause, and then you fix the problem. End of story.

Yes, when you have a really huge application, then your top layer can catch on `RuntimeException` - but only to log that information and give a somehow helpful message to your user.

Yes, there are certain RuntimeExceptions that you can catch, for example NumberFormatException when parsing input strings that are supposed to be numbers. But as said, catching NPE to return -1 is simply wrong. It hides an error condition and makes it close to impossible to predict how your code will continue from there.

In your specific case: simply make sure that you do not invoke the method with null arguments. Or, if you really want to allow passing null arguments, you can put something like

```
Objects.requireNonNull(var, "var must not be null)
```

in the first lines of your method (one check for each parameter that might be null). Then you make it at least explicit that passing null will make the method throw an npe, even with a nice clear error message.

Comment: Thanks! In that case, can I do something like propagating an exception to the caller method if quiz or student is null? Then using getMessage from there. It compiles and works fine.

Comment: Maybe my last update helps. But not sure if I got your question.

Answer (score 0):

You should not catch NullpointerException according to `Effective Java` book. It's usually a programming mistake. Also see here: [Should I always not catch NullPointerException?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265940/should-i-always-not-catch-nullpointerexception)

I would do:

```
public double calculateDifference(String studentName, String quizName) 
{
    if (studentName == null || quizName == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Student name: " + studentName + ", quizName: " + quizName);
    }
    Quiz quiz = quizDAO.retrieve(quizName);
    double averageScore = quiz.getAverageScore();
    Student student = quiz.getStudent(studentName);
    double score = student.getScore();
    return score - averageScore;
}
```

Comment: Still not so good. You are not giving a message, so when debugging this later on, you have no idea which of the two arguments is null.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of catching the `NullPointerException` within the `calculateDifference()` method. It would perhaps be better to declare that the method throws an some exception, so that the user of the method is aware that something can go wrong.

Maybe you should consider using `IllegalArgumentException`, and doing a check for `null` values in your method.

```
public double calculateDifference(String studentName, String quizName) 
  throws IllegalArgumentException {

  Quiz quiz = quizDAO.retrieve(quizName);
  if(quiz == null)
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("There is no such quiz!");

  double averageScore = quiz.getAverageScore();
  Student student = quiz.getStudent(studentName);
  double score = student.getScore();
  return score - averageScore;
}
```

However, the downside of using `RuntimeException`s like `NullPointerException` and `IllegalArgumentException` is that even though they are declared as thrown by the method, they are not enforced, so the caller doesn't have to catch them at all. Therefore, if you are willing to go to the trouble of writing your own subclass of `Exception`, it would be best to throw this, since then the user of the method will have to handle the exception.