# Lint warns of possible exception even though the exception is caught

Tags: android, android-studio

I have a try block and a catch block where NullPointerExceptions are caught. However, Lint warns that a statement in the try block may cause a NullPointerException, even though the exception will be caught. Why doesn't lint recognise that I have handled the possibility of the exception?

I am using Android Studio 3. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The linter's job is to warn you of code that *could* be a problem. One of the built-in rules checks for dereferences that could cause `NullPointerException`s; it doesn't then check to see if this exception is caught.

However, I'm left wondering why you `catch (NullPointerException e)` instead of simply checking for `null` values and then proactively handling them.

Comment: In future, that is what I will do.

Answer (score 2):

As written [here](https://wiki.sei.cmu.edu/confluence/display/java/ERR08-J.+Do+not+catch+NullPointerException+or+any+of+its+ancestors),

> **Programs must not catch java.lang.NullPointerException**. A NullPointerException exception thrown at runtime indicates the existence of an underlying null pointer dereference that must be fixed in the application code. Handling the underlying null pointer dereference by catching the NullPointerException rather than fixing the underlying problem is inappropriate for several reasons. **First, catching NullPointerException adds significantly more performance overhead than simply adding the necessary null checks [Bloch 2008]. Second, when multiple expressions in a try block are capable of throwing a NullPointerException, it is difficult or impossible to determine which expression is responsible for the exception because the NullPointerException catch block handles any NullPointerException thrown from any location in the try block. Third, programs rarely remain in an expected and usable state after a NullPointerException has been thrown.** Attempts to continue execution after first catching and logging (or worse, suppressing) the exception rarely succeed.
>
> Likewise, programs must not catch RuntimeException, Exception, or Throwable. Few, if any, methods are capable of handling all possible runtime exceptions. When a method catches RuntimeException, it may receive exceptions unanticipated by the designer, including NullPointerException and ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Many catch clauses simply log or ignore the enclosed exceptional condition and attempt to resume normal execution; this practice often violates ERR00-J. Do not suppress or ignore checked exceptions. Runtime exceptions often indicate bugs in the program that should be fixed by the developer and often cause control flow vulnerabilities.

So, it appears like intentional behavior when Android Studio "ignores" NullPointerException catch blocks, and you should not be catching NullPointerException, instead just check for null.

See also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265940/when-is-it-ok-to-catch-nullpointerexception) question.