# Properly handle null value from SQL query?

Tags: java

I use this code to get Merchant name by ID.

```
@GetMapping("pages")
public Page<WpfPaymentsDTO> pages(@RequestParam(value = "page") int page, @RequestParam(value = "size") int size) {
    return wpfPaymentsService.findAll(page, size)
                             .map(g -> WpfPaymentsDTO.builder()
                             .id(g.getId())
                             .status(g.getStatus())
                             .merchant_id(getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id()))
                             .build());  
}

private String getMerchantName(int id) {      
    Optional<Merchants> obj = merchantService.findById(id);       
    return obj.get().getName();
}
```

But when name is not found I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: null` at this line: `.merchant_id(getMerchantName(g.getMerchant_id()))`

Is there some way to set empty string and not to break the code when Object is not found?

Comment: Just add obj.ifPresent() check in getMerchantName method. If it is true use your code. Else return empty string.

Comment: You can try including the code nested inside a "try, catch" expression, capturing the NullPointerException to prevent it from stopping the code

Comment: @PabloAlvarez No. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18265940/when-is-it-ok-to-catch-nullpointerexception

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of calling `obj.get().getName()` use more optional-way solution like:

```
obj.map(Merchants::getName).orElse("");
```

which will return empty string when `Merchants` is not found. You can change `""` in code above to any other default value which is more appropriate to your case.

If `g.getMerchant_id()` can be `null` code below will also handle this situation:

```
private String getMerchantName(Integer id) {      
    return Optional.ofNullable(id)
        .flatMap(i -> merchantService.findById(i))
        .map(Merchants::getName)
        .orElse(<default value>);
}
```

It will turn `id` into optional so when it will be `null` this code will just return `<default value>` otherwise it will use `id` to find `Merchants` and then get its name. `flatMap` is here to remove nested optionals.

Comment: g.getMerchant_id() is empty in some cases. How I can handle this case?

Comment: Change `getMerchantName` method signature to: `private String getMerchantName(Integer id)` and then inside it's body `return Optional.ofNullable(id).flatMap(i -> merchantService.findById(i)).map(<the same code as in map from my answer>).orElse(<default value>)`

Comment: bad news. I get at this line `.contract_id(getContractName(g.getContract_id()))` java.lang.NullPointerException: null this is because probably `g.getMerchant_id()` is empty. Is there some solution for this?

Comment: I don't see line that you mentions in your question.

Comment: I cut it in order to save space but the code is the same.

Answer (score 1):

```
private String getMerchantName(int id) {      
    Optional<Merchants> obj = merchantService.findById(id);    

    return obj.isPresent() ?  obj.get().getName() : "";
}
```

Comment: `ifPresent` takes a consumer, it is not an expression.

Comment: That one is not `ifPresent`, it's `isPresent`. In any case, this is an antipattern, and using `map` and `orElse` should be preferred.

Comment: Oh yes it is isPresent

Comment: I changed my answer

Answer (score 1):

You can return an empty string to avoid the `NPE` if the name is null :

```
private String getMerchantName(int id) {      
    Optional<Merchants> obj = merchantService.findById(id);       
    return obj.isPresent() ?  obj.get().getName() : "";
}
```

Then the method `merchant_id` should handle an empty string and perhaps throws an exception (`IllegalArgumentException` for example).

Comment: I get The method ifPresent(Consumer<? super Merchants>) in the type Optional<Merchants> is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: Sorry, the method is `Optional<T>.isPresent()`.

Comment: `isPresent` followed by `get` is an anti-pattern. This is what `orElse` was invented for.

Comment: Looks like I'm facing one more issue. g.getMerchant_id() is empty in some cases. So I need to add here case also to handle null value.

Answer (score 0):

I think we can determine if this object is empty before we return it